# PHP How do I keep session information when moving from Cart to Logged In user?

Tags: php, mysql

I am making my own custom PHP shopping cart. The cart works, I can add products and check out with PayPal.

However, now I have added a new element to the mix. I am trying to integrate the cart with php-login.net script, forcing users to login before they can view the cart and pay.

The login/register script works, but after logging in, when the user is returned to "view_cart.php" there are no products in the cart.

The flow is like this:

**"products.php" -> "login.php" -> "view_cart.php" -> "paypal.com" -> "process-payment.php"**

there is a session created at products.php, and it seems to be erased when the new session is created at login.php, so no products show when the user gets to view_cart.php...

Any ideas how i can make these sessions share? Thanks!

Comment: Are you calling `session_start();` at the top of each page?

Comment: `var_dump(session_name())` in both scripts, ensure they match, and that you're getting a cookie with the returned name. If not, check for `session_start` as mentioned above.

Comment: Your question title does not match the question in the description.

Comment: Description of the question modified to absolutely no valuable information about the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your cart should have an ID.

Get the ID of the cart before you go through the login process.

Do the login process.

Get the new session id

Update your cart entry in the db with the new session id.